# Did Hendrix and Clapton preform together?

Tags: history, jimi-hendrix

Many years ago while listening to Stephen Stills 1 with my father, he mentioned that the track [Go Back Home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pd9VNlquFlE) was the only studio recording that featured both Jimi Hendrix and Eric Clapton playing guitar together. There were of course famous live performances featuring them both, but for sound recorded in a studio this was supposed to be the only occurrence.

I know that the album was released shortly after Jimi's death, and dedicated to him, but it is hard to even get confirmation that these are the two guitarists who are playing on the track.

The [Wikipedia page for the album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Stills_(album)) almost confirms this, but the exact phrase used is "the only *album* to which both Eric Clapton and Jimi Hendrix supplied guitar work" (italics mine) which doesn't quite match up, and the list of contributors by song only mentions Eric Clapton as the guitarist on Go Back Home, whereas Jimi supplied guitar for Old Times Good Times.

Is anyone able to supply a counter example to disprove this, or perhaps prove it via a quote from one of the two? Or should I be asking elsewhere?

Comment: "preform" -> "perform"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They did not perform together.  According to [this interview](https://www.loudersound.com/features/q-a-stephen-stills), they played on 2 separate tracks.

> **On your first solo album (1970) you pulled off a coup getting Clapton and Jim Hendrix to play on Go Back Home and Old Times, Good
>   Times respectively.**
>
> In California we had that jazz theme where everyone could be on anyone
>   else’s record. Not exactly piggybacking by me, because my other groups
>   had already sold apace. I bumped into Eric one evening, and he came by
>   and the night degenerated into an endless jam of The Champs’ Tequila.
>   Then we did the album track in the studio. His solo was one take and
>   he got a fabulous sound. His greatest solo? It inspired me. Forty
>   years later I might just have the chops to emulate him. Hendrix was a
>   god. I saw him play close up, and I saw him with a band many times. It
>   was always a startling experience. Oddly, I don’t think he ever quite
>   got that magic I saw down on his records.

The use of the word "respectively" indicates each guitarist was present on one track only.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I was convinced listening to the rhythm guitar on Go Back Home that it was Jimi, but it must just be Stephen playing in his style.